# How to remove badges on springboard icon when application is relaunched?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4, badge

I am developing an http message related application. In that application when I get a new message from the server, the message count will show on the springboard icon. After reading, the message count will decrease. Now the problem is that my messages count is 2. In that time I removed the application and installed it again.  This time the badges count is showing removed application count like 2.

How do I remove the badge count when the application is installed newly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setApplicationIconBadgeNumber:0];
```

Answer (score 0):

in the app delegate class in `- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions` function put this line of code

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setApplicationIconBadgeNumber:0];
```

Hope this helps

Comment: thank you for showing solution. Now problem is before didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: icon is showing on spring board. at that time badge count is showing on icon. ofter "- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary )launchOptions" ofter this badge count is not getting?

Comment: i will keep holding the badge icon counter on the spring board until the user open the application.